# How to find string that contain dash in a string

Tags: c++, stl

I try to get the position of the string "-a" with this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
string command("test –a string");
size_t pos = command.find("-a");
cout << "position found = " << pos << endl;
}
```

this produce this output:

```
position found = 4294967295
```

If I remove the '-' it's work as expected. 8 is returned.

Comment: I'd advise you to use the `getopt` function family to parse arguments.

Comment: @zneak [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) searches for a substring.

Comment: Thanx, That's pretty stupid! I cut/paste this string from my mail client and code the rest of the application. The problem was there. !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the [`string::npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) value returned, because the library thinks that it cannot find `-a` in the string.

The reason for this is that you use different dashes a long dash `–` in the string and a short dash `-` in the search string.

Once you replace the character with the correct one in both places, your code starts working fine ([demo](http://ideone.com/oli5LB)).

Answer (score 2):

It means that there are different the first characters.

You can check this using the first characters and placing them in statement

```
std::cout << ( '–' == '-' ) << std::endl;
```

As they are different function find returns value `std::string::npos` that is defined as `std::string::size_type( -1 )` or equal to 4294967295

Answer (score 2):

If you look really close you will find the '–' is no '-'.